# Как сделать свою библиотеку доступной для добавления через gradle implementation?

Tags: android, github, gradle

Я понимаю, как создать Android библиотеку и как залить код на Github, а вот как сделать эту библиотеку доступной для скачивания через интернет с помощью стандартного механизма добавления зависимостей gradle? Т.е. как сделать так, чтобы мою библиотеку можно было добавить в любой проект с помощью скрипта:

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
}
```

Насколько я понимаю, это нужно делать с помощью [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/), но как именно это сделать?

Comment: JitPack заморочно при подключении (надо добавлять репозиторий). Лучше сделать [публикацию на bintray](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-and-publishing-an-android-library--cms-24582) с доступом из JCenter  , тогда будет работать, как и другие сторонние библиотеки

Comment: в инструкции по ссылке выше можно выбрать русский язык вверху страницы.

Answer (score 2):

Способов публикации множество, я знаю по крайней мере 4. Наверняка их больше.

Для публикации на [bintray](https://bintray.com/), кроме очевидных шагов типа заведения логина в bintray, нужно в Gradle прописать, что-то типа:

```
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

//blah-blah


publish {

    def groupProjectID = 'com.mylibrary'
    def artifactProjectID = 'mylibrary'
    def publishVersionID = '0.1.0'

    userOrg = 'my user name'
    repoName = 'mylibrary'
    groupId = groupProjectID
    artifactId = artifactProjectID
    publishVersion = publishVersionID
    desc = 'mylibrary description'
    website = 'https://github.com/myusername/MyLibrary'
}
```

Ну и т.д.

Пошаговая [инструкция здесь](https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/6-easy-steps-to-upload-your-android-library-to-bintray-jcenter-59e6030c8890)

Comment: Если вам помог ответ - отметьте его как лучший!